The ngx-scanner is not working in devices
I'm trying to use ngx-scanner (https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner) but after following the instructions it does not work. In PC is working but in other devices no (phone, tablet...). I have tested in iPhone, iPad and Android. In PC I have tested in Chrome and it worked fine.
I have the following code:
component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ZXingScannerModule } from '@zxing/ngx-scanner'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-validate-user',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ZXingScannerModule],
  templateUrl: './validate-user.component.html',
  styleUrl: './validate-user.component.css'
})
export class ValidateUserComponent {
}

component.html
<zxing-scanner></zxing-scanner>

